# OS X 10.11.5 hangs occasionally for 30 seconds for multitasking, gestures and the Dock

Tags: macos, dock, performance

Since a few weeks (maybe since updating from 11.3) my system (MacBook Pro Retina 13" 16 GB RAM) hangs for about 30 seconds every now and then. I am able to use the app where the focus is on, e.g. browser but I can not use the Dock or multitask or use any gestures.

I have already tried to reinstall OS X from Recovery HD. Surprisingly the system downloaded OS X and installed it, but it is not a "clean" install. All my apps and settings are still here ... and the problem as well.

What could be the reason for it and how could I track it down to fix it?

Comment: Can you have activity monitor running and see if you can capture what processes are doing what when the hang occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I was not able to solve it before reinstalling, BUT I found the problem after I have reinstalled the system. The short answer is, the plst of the dock was the problem. Exchanged it, problem gone.

Long answer: I made a 1:1 image copy to an external SSD and reinstalled the system. Then copied back all the config files. The problem apeard once I exchanged the dock plst. In fact I do believe that Google App Launcher was causing this problem. The icon resisted inside the dock and Google discontinued this app in July which is when the problem started to appear. I removed the app icon and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, it's not just you. Many Mac users are experiencing this same issue, including me. It is thought to be a bug in 10.11.4 and I suggest you upgrade to 10.11.5 or downgrade (if you have a backup) to 10.11.3.

In my case, I haven't had an issue or a freeze since I upgraded to 10.11.5. It works great.

See: http://www.macrumors.com/2016/05/13/macbook-pro-system-freezes-os-x-10-11-4/

Answer (score 0):

Apple issued a notice recently about the freezing 13" Retina MBPs: https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht206594

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I have all Software up to date but the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can start to check what the heck is causing it with the activity monitor and system logs?

- Launchpad > Other > Console
- Launchpad > Other > Activity Monitor

Check what is taking up all your memory. I have a memory clean app called **FreeMemory Pro** which checks if memory is low, when low it frees memory, but when doing this everything freezes as this takes all the memory to clear other memory as I set the algorithm to aggressive and not classic.

So this is expected, maybe there is an app in the background that is doing the same that you didn't know about. Have a look at Console and Activity Monitor and let us know! :)